# How assign task to pooled group in alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco

Cosider a code:

```
<potentialOwner>
    <resourceAssignmentExpression>
        <formalExpression>${sc_groupProperty.properties.authorityName}</formalExpression>
    </resourceAssignmentExpression>
</potentialOwner>
```

When `formalExpression` uses task property `sc_groupProperty` which is association to group of users everything wroks. But when it is changed to

```
<formalExpression>SOME_GROUP</formalExpression>
```

or

```
<formalExpression>group(SOME_GROUP)</formalExpression>
```

Created task become unassigned. Is there way to use hardcoded value instead of creating task property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real Alfresco's group name [has prefix `GROUP_`](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-createGroup.html):

```
<formalExpression>GROUP_SOME_GROUP</formalExpression>
```

you can also try [Spring Expression Language (SpEL) literal expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-literal):

```
<formalExpression>#{'GROUP_SOME_GROUP'}</formalExpression>
```

**Updated**

While formal expression is `GROUP_SOME_GROUP`, in alfresco UI you should create with name `SOME_GROUP`.

Comment: `<formalExpression>GROUP_SOME_GROUP</formalExpression>` does not work

Comment: Updated question.